# Migrate from ExpeditedSSL to Free Heroku SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns

Unfortunately after reading through heroku's documentation it is unclear as to how one should migrate from ExpeditedSSL to using herokus free SSL. I am currently using ExpeditedSSL w/ the SSL endpoint. I would like to use Heroku's free Automated Certificate Management (ACM) however the instructions (linked below) say to manually add a SSL certificate, which defeats the purpose of using heroku free ACM.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#migrate-from-ssl-endpoint-to-heroku-ssl

I don't mind a little bit of downtime so my thought process is to:

1) Remove ExpeditedSSL and SSL endpoint add-ons

2) Run "heroku certs:auto:enable"

3) Wait 45 - 60 minutes to fully generate a TLS certificate

4) Run "heroku domains" to see my new DNS target (I think?)

5) Update my DNS settings to point to this new DNS target.

Comment: I suspect you'll want to move step #1 down after #5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did:

1) I ran "heroku certs:auto:enable"

2) I waited until it said "status failed" and then changed my DNS settings to the one that they told me to (can be seen under "heroku domains")

3) Waited one hour and then removed expeditedSSL and the SSL add-on.